# Query User by ID QuickBlox

Tags: quickblox

I'm building an app using the QuickBlox SDK. I have the user's ID stored and need to use that ID to retrieve the user object. Essentially I need to query for the user by ID and retrieve the user object How is this possible?

I attempted to use the userWithID method but it seems this has been deprecated.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check `QBUsers.getUser`? I'm using Android SDK v2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

As per QuickBlox officail doc , the method you find is deprecated but you can use this below method to get user(s) by user(s) id

[official doc of QuickBlox for android](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Retrieve_Users_by_IDs)

```
QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(50);

ArrayList<Integer> usersIds = new ArrayList<>();
usersIds.add(qbChatDialog.getRecipientId());//set user id(s) here

QBUsers.getUsersByIDs(usersIds, pagedRequestBuilder).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
@Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle params) {
        //here you can get User(S) detail in users arrayList
        String email = users.get(0).getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
        Log.e("error" , errors.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **QB.users.listUsers** to retrieve the user object from userid. I had attached source code here.It's work for me

```
var userId = 18767586;
var params = {
   filter: { field: 'id', param: 'in', value: [userId] },
   order: { sort: 'desc', field: 'id' }
   };

   QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        console.log("errMsg ==> ", err);
    } else {
        _.each(result.items, function(item) {
            console.log("User Object ", item.user);
            console.log(item.user.full_name);
            // here you can get the user
        });
    }
   });
```

This solution has been found from http://qaoverflow.com/question/quickblox-filtering-custom-objects-with-javascript/